# How do I solve a limit when direct substitution gives division by zero?

Tags: limits

I have this limit.
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2+x+1}{x-1}$$
And direct substitution gives zero. What do I do? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's typed correctly?  When I plug in $x = 0$ I get $-1$, not $0$.

Comment: @DMcMor yeah sorry I corrected it

Comment: *How* do you get $0$? If $x=1$, then $x^2+x+1=3$.

Comment: Direct substitution gives you 3/0 which is undefined which is an unremovable discontinuity.

Comment: It;s $x+2+\dfrac3{x-1}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner and how do we get there? Would you please clarify?

Comment: @mrsamy I think it's 0

Comment: @CamilaA.: sorry, I meant to say $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x-1}$.

Comment: @CamilaA.:  cf. [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the limit does not exist.

To get a feel for why this is:

If $x$  is a number very close to $1$, but  just a little bit bigger than $1$ (say $x =1 + 0.01$), what does that ratio look like?

On the other hand, if $x$  is a number very close to $1$, but  just a little bit smaller than $1$ (say $x =1 - 0.01 $), what does that ratio look like?

More explicitly, and even more 'rigorously' (sort of): if $x$ is a number very close to $1$, whether $x$ is a bit bigger or a bit smaller than $1$, the numerator $x^2+x+1$ is very close to $3$. Clearly. On the other hand, if $x$ is more than $1$ (but close to $1$), the denominator $x-1$ is very close to $0$ , but positive. So the ratio
$$ \text{approximately } 3\over \text{positive teensy} $$ is a large number.

On the other hand, if $x$ is close to, but smaller than $1$, the denominator $x-1$ is negative, so that the ratio
$$\text{approximately }3\over \text{negative teensy}$$
is a large negative number.

For a limit to exist (even if one allows 'infinity' as a value), there must be ONE value. Here we have two differing possibilities (plus a lot, and minus a lot). Hence there is no unique limit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The limit does not exist.

To prove it,
$\forall G>0$ we need to find $\delta$ s.t. $\forall x$ satisfy $|x-1|<\delta$ we have
$|\frac{x^2+x+1}{x-1}|>G$

Let $|x-1|<1$,
we have $1<(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}<7$,

So,$|\frac{x^2+x+1}{x-1}|=|\frac{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}{x-1}|>|\frac{1}{x-1}|$

Let $|\frac{1}{x-1}|>G$, we have $|x-1|<\frac{1}{G}$.

So,we take $\delta=\min(1,\frac{1}{G})$

Answer (score 1):

Limit does not exist in this case

$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{x^2+x+1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1^+}(x+2+\frac{3}{x-1})=\infty$

$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{x^2+x+1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}(x+2+\frac{3}{x-1})=-\infty$